# Richfaces maven-resource-dependency-plugin SLF4J Build-Error

Tags: java, maven, richfaces, maven-3, slf4j

when I try to use the org.richfaces.cdk.maven-resource-dependecy-plugin version 3.3.3.Final (or 3.3.4.Final) with Maven 3.0.4 I got this error:

> SLF4J: The requested version 1.6.99 by your slf4j binding is not
>   compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10] SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
>
> ...
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.richfaces.cdk:maven-resource-dependency-plugin:3.3.4.Final:assembly-resources
>   (default) on project myproject-web: Execution default of goal
>   org.richfaces.cdk:maven-resource-dependency-plugin:3.3.4.Final:assembly-resources
>   failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing
>   org.richfaces.cdk:maven-resource-dependency-plugin:3.3.4.Final:assembly-resources:
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

Checking the pom´s dependency hierarchy shows only slf4j jars in version 1.7.2 and 1.7.5.

thx

Edit (the plugin config):

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.richfaces.cdk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resource-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.4.Final</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webSourceDirectory>
                        <scriptFilePath>custom-dependencies.js</scriptFilePath>
                        <styleFilePath>custom-dependencies.xcss</styleFilePath>
                        <afterScriptIncludes>
                            <afterScriptInclude>js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js</afterScriptInclude>
                            <afterScriptInclude>js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js</afterScriptInclude>
                            <afterScriptInclude>js/jquery.blockUI.min.js</afterScriptInclude>
                            <afterScriptInclude>js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js</afterScriptInclude>
                            <afterScriptInclude>js/uniqaCommonScript.js</afterScriptInclude>
                            <afterScriptInclude>js/datepicker.js</afterScriptInclude>
                            <afterScriptInclude>js/svp.js</afterScriptInclude>
                        </afterScriptIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>assembly-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant plugin config from your pom. Also, try upgrading maven -- 3.0.4 is rather old.

Comment: And ask at richfaces for their plugin...cause it looks the plugin seemed to be the culprit.

Comment: Updated Maven to 3.2.3, the same error occurs.